# how to prevent changes in the grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, startup, root

When you start the machine and press shift to bring up grub menu, and you press e to make changes in the menu that starts off with `setparams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-30genric'`, how do you prevent people from making changes to that menu like adding `ro recovery nomodeset`

Comment: It's not because I've done that and it still doesn't stop me from changing what  a hacker would need to bypass that.

Comment: So you're saying you set a password for entry, but was able to edit *and boot* that entry?

Comment: No what I'm say is when boot and you press advanced options then press e to make changes to the text I can still do that, I don't want to be able to do that needs to be password protected.

Comment: What difference does that make, when you still can't boot from the modified entry?

Comment: because when you change the splash line to ro recover nomodeset you can still get to root  thats why I want the menu before password protected

Comment: Again: Can you boot from a password-protected entry even after modifying it?

Comment: No the problem is it's not protected to begin with

Comment: @RandolAlbert and muru said: password protect it as shown in the 1st comment. That way you can NOT boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [this page here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) in the **Superuser & Password Designation** section, you will see that it specifically states that:

> Note: GRUB 2 1.99 in 12.04 LTS doesn't protect submenu, ie. command
>   line, entry editing and access to entries is not protected! See bug
>   718670.

**However**, they claim that the work around would be to add `export superusers` to the `/etc/grub.d/00_header` file.  The example looks like the following lines added to the bottom of the file:

```
cat << EOF
set superusers="user1"
password user1 password1
export superusers
EOF
```

after those lines are added to your user information, update the grub so the settings take effect:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I just tested this on my own system, and as soon as I selected `Advanced Options` it asked for a username and password.  However, once you type it in, it is stored for that session and you can edit all lines, even the main Ubuntu entry.  If I rebooted the system, then pressed `e` on the first entry of Ubuntu, it asked for the username and password.

**NOTE: this does not protect if someone boots the host to Live media.**  The only way to protect against that would be to use full drive encryption, but that is for a whole other topic.

Hope this helps!